# Understanding the scalar product in the duality

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

I was trying to solve an exercise for my class, but then I have found somewhere a solution. I need to understand the meaning of a certain step. The exercise and the solution read as follow.

**Exercise** Consider the space $l^\infty:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\ :\ \sup|x(n)|<\infty\}$ equipped with the usual $\sup$ norm. Let $(\delta_n)_n\subset (l^\infty)'$ be defined as $ \langle\delta_n,x\rangle:=x(n).$ Show that it does not exist any subsequence of $(\delta_n)_n$ weakly convergent in $(l^\infty)'$.

**Solution** Take a subsequence $(\delta_{h_k})_k$ of $(\delta_n)_n$, where $(h_k)$ is an increasing sequence of positive integers. By definition we have:

$$ \delta_{h_k} \rightharpoonup \delta\iff\langle f,\delta_{h_k}\rangle\rightarrow\langle f,\delta\rangle, \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ f\in(l^{\infty})'' \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1)$$

$(*)$ By duality the funcion $\langle\cdot,x\rangle:(l^\infty)'\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous and linear functional for any $x\in l^\infty$, thus the previous implications reads:

$$ \delta_{h_k} \rightharpoonup \delta\Rightarrow\langle \delta_{h_k},x\rangle\rightarrow\langle \delta,x\rangle, \ \ \ \ \ \ \forall \ x\in l^{\infty}. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Now define the following sequence $$x(n)= \begin{cases} (-1)^k \ \ \ & \text{if} \ n=h_k\\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
Then $\langle \delta_{h_k},x\rangle=x(h_k)=(-1)^k$ does not converge, then the subsequence $\delta_{h_k}$ cannot weakly converge.

**Question** My problem is with the sentence labelled with $(*)$. Can someone help me to understand why we can pass from $(1)$ to $(2)$. Also, why we need $(h_k)$ to be an increasing sequence of positive integers? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

What needs to be shown is that given the subsequence $(\delta_{h_k})$ there is a functional $f\in X''$ such that $(f(\delta_{h_k}))$ does not converge. Now let $x$ be the sequence defined under $(2)$. Then $\hat x:X'\rightarrow \mathbb{K},x'\mapsto x'(x)$ is a bounded linear functional and $\hat x(\delta_{h_k})$ doesn't converge, so $(\delta_{h_k})$ doesn't converge weakly.

Comment: ok, but how the linearity and the continuity of the scalar product allow me to go from (1) to (2) ?

Comment: @the_elder $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is defined by $\langle f,x'\rangle=f(x')$ for all $f\in X'',x'\in X'$. So $(1)$ means that $\delta_{h_k} \rightharpoonup \delta \iff f(\delta_{h_k})\xrightarrow[k\to \infty]{} f(\delta)\  \forall f\in X''$. What your solution calls $\langle\cdot,x\rangle$ is what I called $\hat x$. Now since $\langle\cdot,x\rangle \in X''$, it follows from $(1)$ that if $\delta_{h_k} \rightharpoonup \delta$, we must have $\langle\delta_{h_k},x\rangle \xrightarrow[k\to \infty]{} \langle\delta,x\rangle$, which is what $(2)$ says. But we only have one direction, since not...

Comment: ...all functionals are of the form $\langle,\cdot,x\rangle$.